# How to make every RecyclerView data into one file

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have various `RecyclerView` sets (Adapter & Variable), but there are so many RecyclerViews, so I want to integrate those files into one.

I don't think `Adapter` is possible, but I think variable can.

```
public class recyclerAData {
public Drawable drawable;
public String string1, string2, string3;

public recyclerAData (Drawable drawable, String string1, String string2, String string3) {
    this.drawable = drawable;
    this.string1 = string1;
    this.string2 = string2;
    this.string3 = string3;
}
```

}

```
public class recyclerBData {
public Drawable drawable1, drawable2;
public String string1, string2, string3;

public recyclerBData (Drawable drawable1, Drawable drawable2,  String string1, String string2) {

    this.drawable1 = drawable1;
    this.drawable2 = drawable2;
    this.string1 = string1;
    this.string2 = string2;
}
```

}

Take an example, let's say we have these two `RecyclerView` data, and I want to make these two files into one.

I'd think this was possible..

```
public class recyclerOneData {
public Drawable drawable1, drawable2;
public String string1, string2, string3;

public recyclerAData (Drawable drawable, String string1, String string2, String string3) {
    this.drawable = drawable;
    this.string1 = string1;
    this.string2 = string2;
    this.string3 = string3;
}

public recyclerBData (Drawable drawable1, Drawable drawable2, String string1, String string2) {
    this.drawable1 = drawable1;
    this.drawable2 = drawable2;
    this.string1 = string1;
    this.string2 = string2;
}
```

}

But Android Studio says me there needs a return type, and I cannot go on.
Is there any way to combine these to one? And more on, is there any way to integrate not only variable but adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to acheive here.

But You are creating a method. You should create constructs.

Creating a method will always require a return type.

```
public class recyclerOneData {
public Drawable drawable1, drawable2;
public String string1, string2, string3;

public recyclerOneData (Drawable drawable, String string1, String string2, String string3) {
    this.drawable1 = drawable;
    this.string1 = string1;
    this.string2 = string2;
    this.string3 = string3;
}

public recyclerOneData (Drawable drawable1, Drawable drawable2, String string1, String string2) {
    this.drawable1 = drawable1;
    this.drawable2 = drawable2;
    this.string1 = string1;
    this.string2 = string2;
}
```